# Next and Previous elements angular2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

Hey guys I'm new to **angular2**

tried several ways to achieve this kind of functionality (look at jsfiddle).

What I need is on click it add active class to next element and removes from current element same vice-versa for Prev btn.so that next element will be shown and prev one will be hided. add/remove class or add remove style could work for me..or anything else that can achieve this kind of thing

I have just achieved it with jQuery.

But I just want to implement it with Angular2, anything can work for me

**html:**

```
<ul>
  <li class="active">item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
</ul>

<button  class="prev">prev</button> <button class="next">Next</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.next').click( function(){
    $('.active').next().addClass('active').prev().removeClass('active')
})
$('.prev').click( function(){
    $('.active').prev().addClass('active').next().removeClass('active')
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/svgmc125/

**Edit:**

code updated using help of @pixelbits help

now HTML will be

```
  <li>
      <my-component></my-component>
  </li>
  <li>
      <my-component-1></my-component-1>
  </li>

  <li [class]="slides[selectedIndex] == slide ? 'active': ''" 
                 *ngFor="let slide of slides">
    <img src="../../assets/images/onboarding/slides/{{slide}}.png" alt="">
  </li>
  <li>
      <my-component-2></my-component-2>
  </li>
  <li>
      <my-component-3></my-component-3>
  </li>
```

**ts:**

```
export class SlidesComponent{

  slides: any[];
    selectedIndex: number;
    constructor() {
        this.selectedIndex = 0;
        this.slides = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
    }

    next() {
       ++this.selectedIndex;
    }

    previous() {
        --this.selectedIndex;
    }

 }
```

its all working fine for looped `<li>` but still have issue with remaining `<li>`

Comment: consider a case for "accordion" as well "add class to one and remove from others"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two models in your component class: items array and the selectedIndex.  Bind `class` based on whether the item at the selectedIndex equals the item.

```
@Component({
   selector: 'list',
   template: `
      <ul>
          <li [class]="items[selectedIndex] == item ? 'active': ''" 
                 *ngFor="let item of items">{{ item }}</li>
      </ul>
   `
})
class MyComponent {
    items: string[];
    selectedIndex: number;
    constructor() {
        this.selectedIndex = 0;
        this.items = ["item1", "item2","item3"];
    }

    next() {
       ++this.selectedIndex;
    }

    previous() {
        --this.selectedIndex;
    }

}
```

Comment: this worked for me but again there is one scenario
my html is 
<ul>
     <li>text</li> 
     <li [class]="items[selectedIndex] == item ? 'active': ''" 
                 *ngFor="let item of items">{{ item }}</li>
     <li>text</li> 
<ul>

How it will work for rest 2 LI as well - other 2 LI are not in loop ..those having some static content..but still I want to add/remove active class

Comment: Add the static items to the list as well

Comment: its huge static HTML inside <li> ..calling from diff components 

<li>   
      <my-compenent></my-my-compenent> 
  </li>
        
<li [class]="items[selectedIndex] == item ? 'active': ''" *ngFor="let item of items"><img src="../../assets/images/onboarding/slides/{{item}}.png" alt=""></li>        

<li>   
      <my-compenent2></my-my-compenent2> 
  </li>

<li>   
      <my-compenent3></my-my-compenent3> 
  </li>

and my slides aaray will be 
this.slides = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

Comment: Assign index -1 and -2 to your static items, and use `[class.active]="selectedIndex === -1"` (or -2) on your static elements.

Comment: I added same..but when page loads by default the active class is on LI that have for loop..and not on first LI

Comment: So, initialize this.selectedIndex  to -2 instead of 0. Really, you shouldn't just copy and paste code if you don't understand it first.

Answer (score 6):

All you need is to have, in your component, a field referencing the active item (or its index):

```
items: Array<string> = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
activeItem: string = items[0];

previous() {
    const currentIndex = this.items.indexOf(this.activeItem);
    const newIndex = currentIndex === 0 ? this.items.length - 1 : currentIndex - 1;
    this.activeItem = this.items[newIndex];
}

next() {
    const currentIndex = this.items.indexOf(this.activeItem);
    const newIndex = currentIndex === this.items.length - 1 ? 0 : currentIndex + 1;
    this.activeItem = this.items[newIndex];
}
```

and in the view:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" [class.active]="item === activeItem">{{ item }}</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<ul>
  <li #item class="active">item1</li>
  <li #item>item2</li>
  <li #item>item3</li>
</ul>
```

```
@ViewChildren('item') items:QueryList<ElementRef>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  var active = this.items.toArray()
      .filter(i => i.nativeElement.classList.contains('active'));
  console.log(active[0].nativeElement);
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question, could you please read and update your answer accordingly

Comment: You already accepted an answer. I think the other answers are a better fit for your use case anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your thinking around the problem needs to be different when dealing with Angular vs jQuery. In Angular, it's helpful to think of the HTML/View as a visual reflection of your data model in code.

So, for example, let's say you have a component like:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li [class.active]="current == 0">item1</li>
      <li [class.active]="current == 1">item2</li>
      <li [class.active]="current == 2">item3</li>
    </ul>

    <button class="prev" (click)="previous()">prev</button> 
    <button class="next" (click)="next()">Next</button>
  `
})
export class ListComponent {
   current = 0;

   next() {
     if (current == 0) {
       current = 2;
     } else {
       current = current - 1;
     }
   }

   next() {
     current = (current + 1) % 3;
   }
}
```

The above component will implement the functionality as you described. But more importantly is to understand what Angular is about.
You should always try to envision the raw data that you're trying to display in your component, and implement logic in your component to change that data as you need. 
Then your template simply becomes a visual representation of your data, along with hooks to the logic to change that data based on user input.

So, in the example given, [class.active]="current == 0" says to either add or remove the active class based on whether the current variable is zero or not.

And (click)="previous()" means to call the previous method in your class whenever a click event is fired from that button.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `ng-class` to apply the class `active` based on the current index of the li item.

The HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MainController as main">
  <ul>
    <li ng-class="{'active' : main.active == 1}">item1</li>
    <li ng-class="{'active' : main.active == 2}">item2</li>
    <li ng-class="{'active' : main.active == 3}">item3</li>
  </ul>

  <button class="prev" ng-click="main.back()">prev</button>
  <button class="next" ng-click="main.next()">Next</button>
</div>
```

The Controller

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainController', function() {

  this.active = 1;

  this.max = 3;

  this.next = function(){
    this.active++;
    if(this.active > this.max) this.active = this.max;
  }

  this.back = function(){
    this.active--;
    if(this.active < 1) this.active = 1;
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/7p6IxAnGstTWVsrrR8FX?p=preview

Comment: The OP is asking about Angular 2, not AngularJS.

Comment: Care to provide a reference? Because, you know, I use and teach both versions, and thus quite know the difference.

Comment: That's definitely angular 1.x